# Сгенерировать большое и маленькое случайные числа

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

Как с помощью библиотеки `<random>` сгенерировать 2 случайных числа `a, b` таких, что `a` и `b` принадлежат `[0;n), n=const` и `a <= b`?

Знаю, как сделать, чтобы они лежали в `[0;n)`:

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> dist{0, n-1};
```

, но как сделать, чтобы одно было не больше другого?

Comment: Просто сгенерировать два числа, а если второе оказалось больше первого - поменять их местами?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat логично, спасибо)

Comment: Вариантов, наверное, десятки :) - весь вопрос в том, **как** они должны быть распределены...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int a = random;
int b = random;
int x;
if (b>=a) {
    x=b;
    b=a;
    a=x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно и так:

```
template <int f, int s >
class URand {
    std::mt19937 en;
public:
    int  operator ()() {
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> d(f, s);
        return d(en);
    }
};

int main() 
{
    constexpr int n = 100;
    URand<0, n> rn;
    URand<0, n + n> rn2;
    int b = rn(),
        a = rn2() % b; 
    //...
}
```